# Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I've started a server and main page shows correctly, but when i go to other tabs nothing works and throws an error `"Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception".`

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() для сервлета [dispatcher] throw an exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1742)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:220)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:191)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:672)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:720)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:125)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1742)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause

org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'firstController' for bean class [com.dmitryshvalev.springMVC.controllers.FirstController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.dmitryshvalev.springMVC.config.controllers.FirstController]
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:349)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:287)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:90)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1390)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1370)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:184)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:220)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:191)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:672)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:720)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:125)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1742)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: **bean name 'firstController' for bean class [com.dmitryshvalev.springMVC.controllers.FirstController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class**

Comment: but how I should fix it?

Comment: Find out: why you have 2? Do you need 2? (If so maybe name it differently!?)

Comment: (I "guess") one is "component-scanned", the other  (obviously) in `/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check /target/project_name/WEB-INF folders and delete conflicted files were created early. helped me with same problem